# getting error Unfortunately app has stopped working & how to add link that when we click on city the image should be display?

Tags: android

I want to make two dropdownlist boxes one display calender another list display city name.when we click on city they show me certain images which was loaded by that clickable city as well as show date & time of that click.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
Integer[] imageIDs={
            R.drawable.banglore,
            R.drawable.mathura,
            R.drawable.mumbai,
            R.drawable.akkalkot};
    Gallery city=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.city);

     String[] items; 
     TimePicker timePicker;
     DatePicker datePicker;
     int hour,minute;
     static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=0;



     //Initializing my the member of xml file.

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner spin=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_array);

        spin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                city.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.banglore);
                city.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mathura);
                city.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mumbai);
                city.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.akkalkot);


            }
        });
        timePicker=(TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
        timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
        showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        datePicker=(DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datepicker);

        ArrayAdapter<String>aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,items);

        spin.setAdapter(aa);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>parent,View view,int position,long id)
            {
                int index=parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected item:"+ items[index],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //selection.setText(items[position]);

            }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }
        });




    }

     protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {               
        switch (id) 
        {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener,hour,minute,false);
        }
        return null;            
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = 
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener()        
    {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,int hourOfDay,int minuteOfHour)
        {
                hour=hourOfDay;
                minute=minuteOfHour;


                SimpleDateFormat timeFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
                Date date = new Date(0,0,0,hour,minute);
                String strDate=timeFormat.format(date);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have selected"+strDate,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                 
        }           
    };  


    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Date selected:"
            +(datePicker.getMonth()+1)+
            "/"+datePicker.getDayOfMonth()+
            "/"+datePicker.getYear()+"\n"+
            "Time selected:"+timePicker.getCurrentHour()+
            ":"+timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
    }


}
just give onclick event to time & date.
```

This is XML file of my assignment

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >




    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Assignment1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="I am all set!" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datepicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timepicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mumb"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mumbai"
/>

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />"

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/math"
        android:layout_width="46dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mathura"
 />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/akka"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:src="@drawable/akkalkot"
/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bang"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/banglore" 
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

This is manifest file of my assignment.

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.incraft.assignment"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.incraft.assignment.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The Logcat Is:

```
12-31 00:51:49.910: D/AndroidRuntime(954): Shutting down VM
12-31 00:51:49.910: W/dalvikvm(954): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a8bb90)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954): Process: com.incraft.assignment, PID: 954
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.incraft.assignment/com.incraft.assignment.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1883)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.incraft.assignment.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:42)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
12-31 00:51:49.980: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  ... 11 more
12-31 00:52:28.678: I/Process(954): Sending signal. PID: 954 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this  `city=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.city)` after `setContentView` in `onCreate`

```
 Gallery city; // declare a instance variable
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    city=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.city); // initialize here
```

`findViewById` looks for a view int he current inflated layout. So you need  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` then initialize your views.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize `city` outside of the `onCreate` method because the activity hasn't been created yet and therefore the view has not been set. This is where your error occurs:

```
Gallery city=(Gallery)findViewById(R.id.city);
```

So declare it outside of `onCreate`, but initialize inside `onCreate` after you set the view:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    Integer[] imageIDs={
        R.drawable.banglore,
        R.drawable.mathura,
        R.drawable.mumbai,
        R.drawable.akkalkot};
    Gallery city;

    String[] items; 
    TimePicker timePicker;
    DatePicker datePicker;
    int hour,minute;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=0;

    //Initializing my the member of xml file.

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        city = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.city);

// ...
```